# When resizing the screen my SVG elements scrambles and lose their position

Tags: html, svg, responsive-design, svg-animate

I made an animation in using several SVG elements combined with some HTML. When the browser is  maximized they behaves well on different screen sizes, but when I resize manually they scramble, and at some point start to disappear. How can I make them stay where they should be?

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
<script>

        /*AnimeJS*/
        var functionBasedDuration = anime({
          targets: '#functionBasedDuration .el1',
          translateX: 600,
          direction: 'alternate',
          loop: false,
          delay:2500,   
          duration: function(el, i, l) {
            return 3200 + (i * 5000);
          }
        }); 
        
        functionBasedDuration = anime({
          targets: '#functionBasedDuration .el2',
          translateX: 800,
          direction: 'alternate',
          loop: false,
          delay:2800,
          duration: function(el, i, l) {
            return 3200 + (i * 5000);
          }
        }); 
        
        functionBasedDuration = anime({
          targets: '#functionBasedDuration .el3',
          translateX: 1000,
          direction: 'alternate',
          loop: false,
          delay:3100,
          duration: function(el, i, l) {
            return 3200 + (i * 5000);
          }
        }); 
        
        functionBasedDuration = anime({
          targets: '#functionBasedDuration .el4',
          translateX: 1200,
          direction: 'alternate',
          loop: false,
          delay:3400,
          duration: function(el, i, l) {
            return 3200 + (i * 5000);
          }
        }); 

        /*upper icons*/


        var CSStransforms = anime({
          targets: '#increase .el',
          rotate: '1turn',
          delay: 4500
        });

        var CSStransforms = anime({
          targets: '#rocket .el',
          rotate: '1turn',
            delay: 5500
        });

        var CSStransforms = anime({
          targets: '#bulb .el',
          rotate: '1turn',
            delay: 6500
        });

        var CSStransforms = anime({
          targets: '#browser .el',
          rotate: '1turn',
            delay: 7500
        });


        
        /*Tween Lite*/
        var join = $('#divCirc');
        TweenLite.to(join, 3, {height: "140",width: "140px", left:"50%", opacity: .5, ease:Power3.easeOut});
        TweenLite.to(join, .8, {height: "70",width: "70px",opacity: 1, top:"120px", left:"120px", delay:1.5, ease:Power4.easeIn});
        

        var firstMainCol= $('#firstMainCol')
        firstMainCol.css('opacity',0);
        TweenLite.to(firstMainCol, 3, {y:"-260", opacity: 1, ease:Power3.easeOut}).delay(9);
        
        var secondMainCol= $('#secondMainCol')
        secondMainCol.css('opacity',0);
        TweenLite.to(secondMainCol, 3, {y:"-260", opacity: 1, ease:Power3.easeOut}).delay(9.5);
        
        var thirdMainCol= $('#thirdMainCol')
        thirdMainCol.css('opacity',0);
        TweenLite.to(thirdMainCol, 3, {y:"-260", opacity: 1, ease:Power3.easeOut}).delay(10);
        
         $('#transparentRect2').on('click',rocket('#rocketFirstCol','#rocketSecondCol','#rocketThirdCol'));
         $('#transparentRect3').on('click',bulb('#bulbFirstCol','#bulbSecondCol','#bulbThirdCol'));
         $('#transparentRect4').on('click',browser('#browserFirstCol','#browserSecondCol','#browserThirdCol'));
        
        function rocket(RocketTxtId1,RocketTxtId2,RocketTxtId3){
                var rocketFirstCol= $(RocketTxtId1)
                rocketFirstCol.css('opacity',0);
                TweenLite.to(rocketFirstCol, 3, {y:"-260", opacity: 1, ease:Power3.easeOut}).delay(1);
            
                var rocketSecondCol= $(RocketTxtId2)
                rocketSecondCol.css('opacity',0);
                TweenLite.to(rocketSecondCol, 3, {y:"-260", opacity: 1, ease:Power3.easeOut}).delay(1.5);
            
                var rocketThirdCol= $(RocketTxtId3)
                rocketThirdCol.css('opacity',0);
                TweenLite.to(rocketThirdCol, 3, {y:"-260", opacity: 1, ease:Power3.easeOut}).delay(1.5);
        } 
        
        function bulb(bulbTxtId1,bulbTxtId2,bulbTxtId3){
                bulbFirstCol= $(bulbTxtId1)
                bulbFirstCol.css('opacity',0);
                TweenLite.to(bulbFirstCol, 3, {y:"-260", opacity: 1, ease:Power3.easeOut}).delay(1);
            
                bulbSecondCol= $(bulbTxtId2)
                bulbSecondCol.css('opacity',0);
                TweenLite.to(bulbSecondCol, 3, {y:"-260", opacity: 1, ease:Power3.easeOut}).delay(1.5);
            
                bulbThirdCol= $(bulbTxtId3)
                bulbThirdCol.css('opacity',0);
                TweenLite.to(bulbThirdCol, 3, {y:"-260", opacity: 1, ease:Power3.easeOut}).delay(1.5);
        } 
        
        function browser(browserTxtId1,browserTxtId2,browserTxtId3){
                browserFirstCol= $(browserTxtId1)
                browserFirstCol.css('opacity',0);
                TweenLite.to(browserFirstCol, 3, {y:"-260", opacity: 1, ease:Power3.easeOut}).delay(1);
            
                browserSecondCol= $(browserTxtId2)
                browserSecondCol.css('opacity',0);
                TweenLite.to(browserSecondCol, 3, {y:"-260", opacity: 1, ease:Power3.easeOut}).delay(1.5);
            
                browserThirdCol= $(browserTxtId3)
                browserThirdCol.css('opacity',0);
                TweenLite.to(browserThirdCol, 3, {y:"-260", opacity: 1, ease:Power3.easeOut}).delay(1.5);
        } 
        
        
                                /* Toogling main text */
        $('#increase, #rectIncrease, #transparentRect1').on('click', function () {
            viewText('.textIncrease');
        } );
        $('#rocket, #rectRocket, #transparentRect2').on('click', function(){
            viewText('.textRocket');
        });
        $('#bulb, #rectBulb, #transparentRect3').on('click', function(){
            viewText('.textBulb');
        });
        $('#browser, #rectBrowser,#transparentRect4 ').on('click', function(){
            viewText('.textBrowser');
        });

        function viewText(textType) {
            $('.textImage').removeClass('active');
            $('.textImage').addClass('inactive');
            $(textType).removeClass('inactive');
            $(textType).addClass('active');
        }
    </script>
```

This is the codepen link to the HTML and CSS code: https://codepen.io/jcrr1985/pen/dKqoRQ

Comment: What browser are you using? I am not seeing the issues you described in Chrome 67.

Comment: Hi, Im using chrome 64, and the svgs gets totally scrambled in chrome and also in firefox.